# Apply filtering to generate a dropdown list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I have the following class and want to filter the dropdown list based on a certain condition.

**Model Classes**

```
public class Option
{
    public int OptionID { get; set;}
    public string OptionName { get; set; }

    public int TechnicalCharacteristicID { get; set; }
    public int LsystemID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OptionValue> OptionValues { get; set; }
    public virtual TechnicalCharacteristic TechnicalCharacteristic { get; set; }
    public virtual Lsystem Lsystem { get; set; }
}

public class OptionValue
{
    public int OptionValueID { get; set; }
    public string OptionVal { get; set; }
    public int OptionID { get; set; }

    public virtual Option Option { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection< SetValue> SetValue { get; set; }
}

public class SetValue
{
    public int SetValueID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public int TcSetID { get; set; }
    public int OptionValueID { get; set; }

    public virtual OptionValue OptionValue { get; set; }
    public virtual TcSet TcSet { get; set; }

}

public class TcSet
{
    public int TcSetID { get; set; }
    public string SetName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "PhysicalUnit")]
    public string PhysicalUnit { get; set; }

    public int TechnicalCharacteristicID { get; set; }
    public int DataFormatID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SetValue> SetValues { get; set; }
    public virtual DataFormat DataFormat { get; set; }
    public virtual TechnicalCharacteristic TechnicalCharacteristic { get; set; }
}

public class TechnicalCharacteristic
{
    public int TechnicalCharacteristicID { get; set; }
    public string TCName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TcSet> TcSets { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
}
```

**What I am trying to achieve**

I want to save values for each option in `SetVal`. The Dropdownlist generated in `SetVal` needs to filtered based on the following condition (I can't implement the condition as such as it uses parameters from other classes)

```
 OptionValue.Option.TechnicalCharacteristicID == TcSet.TCID
```

I have the following controller class. I have equated the select condition with a preset value because I was unable to match the right hand side of the select condition.

I need to display the result of the select in a table. When i try to resolve the existing result to table it shows the type is not IEnumerable, even though it is declared IEnumerable in the model class..

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Create(int OptionValID, int OptionID)
    {
        var model = new SetValue
        {
            OptionValueID = OptionValID
        };
        //var tcid = 
       // ViewBag.OptionValueID = new SelectList(db.OptionValue, "OptionValueID", "OptionVal");
        var tcSet = db.SetValue.Include(x=>x.TcSet).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.OptionValue.Option.TechnicalCharacteristicID==4);
        if (tcSet!=null)
        {
            model.TcSet = tcSet.TcSet;
        }
        ViewBag.TcSetID = new SelectList(db.TcSet, "TcSetID", "SetName");
        return View(model);
    }
```

The parameters for Create come from a function call from the Option Value controller. The parameters are the `OptionValueID` and `OptionID`.

I don't know if I have the right approach for achieving the task.

**Additional Comments**

Even with the preset value the list doesn't work. There are no compile or runtime errors

**Debug details**

I get two values from the select statement, but both the values are the same. It only corresponds to the first value of the row from the required table.

Comment: use the following code to generate your selectlist data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to generate your select list data

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var listOfCat1 = db.TcSets.ToList();

        if (listOfCat1 != null)
        {
            if (listOfCat1.Count>0)
            {
                foreach (var item in listOfCat1)
                {
                    SelectListItem sVM = new SelectListItem();
                    sVM.Value = item.Id.ToString();
                    sVM.Text = item.Name;
                    selectList.Add(sVM);
                }
            }
        }

        return selectList.AsEnumerable();

    }
```

Then, put the following code in your controller before calling the view

```
    ViewBag.ProductCategoriesList = SelectList();
```

In your View, call the dropdown list with the following line of code

```
   <div class="form-group" >
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TcSetID , "Product Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TcSetID , @ViewBag.ProductCategoriesList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "--- Select Tc Set  ---", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "background-color:yellow;border-color:royalblue" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TcSetID , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
  </div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your code. But i have already found another may be not the best practice.

Comment: Lets see what you found. It may help someone else.