# populate dropdown from List<string> values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to populate dropdown list from viewbag and the viewbag is populated from the list. I am having some issues. Can someone please let me know what i am missing

C# Code:

```
public ActionResult ColumnMapping()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (Session["datatable"] != null)
            {
                dt = ((DataTable)Session["datatable"]);
                ViewBag.ColumnMapping = dt;

                List<string> ddlcolumnmapping = columnmappingddl();
                ViewBag.ddlcolmapping = ddlcolumnmapping;
            }            
            return View(dt);
        }
```

.cshtml file:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Column Mapping</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Column Mapping:</div>

@if (ViewBag.ColumnMapping != null)
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
    {
        @col.Caption

       @Html.DropDownList("", new SelectList(ViewBag.ddlcolmapping))

            @*foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                {
                    @Html.Raw(col.Caption + " " + row[col].ToString() + "<br/>")
                }*@
            }
            }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what kind of issues are you having?  Is it not populating?  Is the drop down lot loading?

Comment: Getting an error "Value cannot be null or empty." even though the values are populated in the List<string> and the values are carried in the viewbag.

Comment: you sure columnmappingddl() returns List not null?

Comment: The list in your viewbag has to be a List<SelectListItem>... that's why you aer having a problem. See this for more help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33327821/3777098

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just create a select list from a `List<string>`. It needs an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` or you need a list of a class instance, where you can then pass the property names to use for `Value` and `Text`. So, you're only option here is to use LINQ to select the list of strings into `SelectListItem`s:

```
var options = ddlcolumnmapping.Select(m => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = m,
    Text = m
});
```

Now, you can pass `options` to your dropdown and everything is golden. Also, you don't need to create an actual instance of `SelectList`, and in fact, it's better if you don't. For example, if you set `ViewBag.options` with the value of this `options` variable, then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.options)
```