# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'FK_EthnicOriginID'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can any one help me Please .. 
I want to fill Dropdownlist with model in MVC 
using this code

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.EthnicOrigin = new SelectList(patientRepository.GetEthnicOrigin().AsEnumerable(), "ID","Name");    
    return view(); 
}
```

And My View is

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FK_EthnicOriginID, (ViewBag.EthnicOrigins) as SelectList, "Ethnic Origins", new { @class = "m-b form-control select2" })
</div>
```

And My Gitter Method id

```
public IQueryable<EthnicOrigin> GetEthnicOrigin()
{
    return context.EthnicOrigins;
}
```

but when i try to run this it gives me the above error

Comment: It means that the value of `ViewBag.EthnicOrigins` is `null` (probably because you did not set it in the POST method before you return the view

Comment: when i debugged the code i found that it have data
and i set anther data from the daatabase

Comment: No doubt you think `ViewBag.EthnicOrigin` is populated but `ViewBag.EthnicOrigins` is `null` (Use view models. **DO NOT** use ViewBag!)

Comment: help me with example please

Comment: Example of what?

Comment: using view model

Comment: Look at the code in the duplicate

Comment: Ahmed, you need to load your SelectList class with a SelectListItem class, one for each entry,which has 2 values, "Value" and "Text". Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33327821/3777098